# Passing parameter to the drill thru report in cognos

Tags: cognos

How to Pass a Calculated Member/measure to a Drill-thru Target Report

In order to avoid using Calculated Members--because from googling some people were saying you could not pass them via Drill-thru--I went back to my FM model and created 3 new measures (High Risk, Low Risk and Medium Risk). Now these will show up in the drill-thru definitions parameter list . . . my only problem is that how can I do a check to see which of the three measures has been selected by a user?
Remember, I basically have a line chart with 3 lines, one for each measure above (High, Medium or Low Risk) by time frame. A user will select a data point, High risk for March or Medium Risk for Semester 2, for example. I then need to pass the value for that datapoint to my Target (2nd) report. How can I check for which of the three measure values they passed through?!?